# Multi-selected values can't be passed to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core

I am trying to select multiple values with Multiselect functionality and pass them to db, but to no avail.

Models' M-M relations

```
        public class Cluster : IEntityBase<string>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }


    }
```

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Cluster> Clusters { get; set; } 
        [ForeignKey("SensorType")]
        public string SensorTypeId { get; set; }
        public SensorType SensorType { get; set; }
```

Repository Pattern

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db; 
public SensorRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) {
 _db = db; 
}

public void Add(SensorVM entity)
        {       
            
            Sensor mappedSensor = new Sensor()
            {
                Id = entity.Id,
                Name = entity.Name,
                Clusters = entity.Clusters,
                SensorTypeId = entity.SensorTypeId,
                SensorType = entity.SensorType,
                APIUrl = entity.APIUrl,
                X = entity.X,
                Y = entity.Y,
                Configuration = entity.Configuration,
                ConfigurationSchema = schema.ToJson(),
                SerialNumber = entity.SerialNumber,
                Interval = entity.Interval,
                IsActive = entity.IsActive
            };                        
            _db.Sensors.Add(mappedSensor);
            _db.SaveChanges();                        
        }
```

Controller code

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Add()
        {                        
            IEnumerable<Cluster> getClusters = _clusterRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            ViewData["Clusters"] = new MultiSelectList(getClusters, "Id", "Name");
    ...
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(SensorVM obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                _sensorRepository.Add(obj);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
```

View code

```
<div class="form-floating py-2 col-12">
            <select asp-for="Clusters" asp-items="(MultiSelectList)@ViewData["Clusters"]" multiselect-search="true" multiple placeholder="-Select Clusters-">
            <span asp-validation-for="Clusters" class="text-danger"></span>
            </select>
 </div>
```

It shows Clusters = null.

I suspect I am missing some sort of Id manipulation - collecting them in a list. Using the M-m relationship, a ClusterSensor table was created in db consisting of SensorId and ClusterId.

The other thing is that I am missing a way to populate the 'selectedValues' parameter of MultiSelectList.

```
public MultiSelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues);
```

Comment: Perhaps at least format the code to remove all the blank lines and excess indentations.  I don't think `...` is valid code; perhaps put some sort of a comment why that is there?  As this is quite related to the database save perhaps show where `_db.` is defined?

Comment: Also Seems odd to have a span inside a `select` element.

Comment: "It shows Clusters = null."Where do you see it ? Do you try to set a breakpoint at `ViewData["Clusters"] = new MultiSelectList(getClusters, "Id", "Name");` to see the value of  ViewData["Clusters"] ?

Comment: @QingGuo by setting a breakpoint at    _sensorRepository.Add(obj);  in the HttpPost method. The Clusters row in the obj says null, albeit a multi selection of values has been done in the Add form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a multi selection of values ,like ClusterIds,we can add a property `ClusterIds` in SensorVM model like:

```
public IEnumerable<Cluster> Clusters { get; set; }

public string[] ClusterIds { get; set; }
```

Then in the view:

```
<div class="form-floating py-2 col-12">
    <select asp-for="ClusterIds" asp-items="(MultiSelectList)@ViewData["Clusters"]" multiselect-search="true" multiple placeholder="-Select Clusters-">
        <span asp-validation-for="ClusterIds" class="text-danger"></span>
    </select>
</div>
```

result:

[image]

Then set the Clusters by the select ClusterId, like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(SensorVM obj)
        {  
        IEnumerable<Cluster> getClusters = _clusterRepository.GetAll().ToList();

        var list = new List<Cluster>();
        foreach (var x in obj.ClusterIds)
        {
           var item = getClusters.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == x);
           list.Add(item);
         }
           obj.Clusters = list;

            ModelState.Remove("Clusters");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                _sensorRepository.Add(obj);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
```

result:

[image]

**Update:**

```
@model SensorVM

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-floating py-2 col-12">
        <select asp-for="ClusterIds" asp-items="(MultiSelectList)@ViewData["Clusters"]" multiselect-search="true" multiple placeholder="-Select Clusters-">
            <span asp-validation-for="ClusterIds" class="text-danger"></span>
        </select>
    </div> 
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: at `foreach (var x in obj.ClusterIds)` is throws an exception:

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Local2 was null.`

Which indicates that the problem lays in the select tag of the view, as the multiselected values for ClusterIds are not being taken.

Comment: Hi @glidziR99 , do you try to add ClusterIds property and  get the  ClusterIds in  SensorVM  ? You can try the update code to select the option and submit to see the  ClusterIds.

Comment: I updated the SensorVM - View model with a `string[] ClusterIds` property (all Ids are of type string in this project), then did the same with the Sensor model, finally mapping the two properties in the repository - `ClusterIds = entity.ClusterIds,`. I also updated the db by doing a migration, but the same problem prevails.

Comment: Hi @glidziR99, ok, View model with a string[] ClusterIds , and  that ClusterIds just use for setting `Clusters = entity.Clusters`, no need to do the same with the Sensor model. Could you get the Clusters by `obj.Clusters = list;`?

Comment: It works now! ClusterIds are being collected in a list and written in the db accordingly. 
How could the list of selected Clusters be depicted in the `<td width="50%">@obj.Clusters</td>` 
element of the Index.cshtml view? 

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Hi @glidziR99 , Great!  Do you want to display the Clusters Id and Name in Index.cshtml view ?   Most way is  `@foreach (var item in Model.Clusters){<td width="50%">@item.Id</td>}`   . Could you create  a new post to describe your problem about  "the list of selected Clusters b e depicted in the <td width="50%">@obj.Clusters</td> element of the Index.cshtml view"  ? You need to add the code of index action method and make sure you can get the  Clusters  in the Index method, then pass the  Clusters  to  Index view.

Comment: On updating the Sensor's multiselected Clusters I applied the same logic and it throws an exception `PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_ClusterSensor"`, thus considers the edit of selected values as new entries. How could this be possibly resolved?

Comment: Hi@glidziR99 , could you create a new post to describe the new problem clearly ? So that others also could see it and help.